# HTML5 animations creating "fizzy" effect on material ui icon shapes

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I'm making a drag and drop module - and around the cloud icon - I'd like to have various little shapes flutter into/out of existence on a loop -- making it look like a fizzy effect you'd see in a bottle of coke. A kind of magical lucky charms thing.

How would I go about animating these shapes in and out of existence on a loop?

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-satoshi-knusw

--
I've tried adding animation like this - but it's not really working
http://jsfiddle.net/zr7sb/10/

```css
    .magic-cloud {
    
      .small {
        font-size: 16px;
      }
    
      .large {
        font-size: 146px;
      }
    
    
      .purple {
        color: #a85e9f;
      }
    
      .blue {
        color: #c9dff7;
      }
    
      .gold {
        color: #fdbd00;
      }
      .lavendar {
        color: #c698c0;
      }
    
    }
    
    
    .bubble {
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    .x1 {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
      -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
      transform: scale(0.9);
      opacity: 0.2;
      -webkit-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
      -moz-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
      -o-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
    }
    
    .x2 {
      left: 200px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
      -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
      transform: scale(0.6);
      opacity: 0.5;
      -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite, sideWays 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
      -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
      -o-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
    }
    .x3 {
      left: 350px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
      -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
      transform: scale(0.8);
      opacity: 0.3;
      -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
      -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
      -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    }
    .x4 {
      left: 470px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
      -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
      transform: scale(0.75);
      opacity: 0.35;
      -webkit-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
      -moz-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
      -o-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
    }
    .x5 {
      left: 150px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
      -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
      transform: scale(0.8);
      opacity: 0.3; 
      -webkit-animation: moveclouds 7s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
      -moz-animation: moveclouds 7s linear infinite;
      -o-animation: moveclouds 7s linear infinite;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes moveclouds { 
      0% { 
          top: 500px;
      }
      100% { 
          top: -500px;
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes sideWays { 
      0% { 
          margin-left:0px;
      }
      100% { 
          margin-left:50px;
      }
    }
    
    @-moz-keyframes moveclouds {     
      0% { 
          top: 500px;
      }
    
      100% { 
          top: -500px;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes moveclouds {
      0% { 
          top: 500px;
      }
      100% { 
          top: -500px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div className="magic-cloud">
  <CloudQueueIcon className="large" />

  <AddIcon className="small gold bubble x1" />
  <RadioButtonUncheckedOutlinedIcon className="small pink bubble x2" />
  <FiberManualRecordIcon className="small purple bubble x3" />

  <AddIcon className="small purple bubble x1" />
  <RadioButtonUncheckedOutlinedIcon className="small lavendar bubble x2" />
  <FiberManualRecordIcon className="small gold bubble x3" />
</div>
```

[image]

I only want it to animate within this region

- latest fork -- need to try and put moving clouds into a function
  https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-dream-08ueh

Here is my version - but the shapes although I can see them floating aren't really showing up -- jsfiddle.net/xpb90keq/3

---

alternative version

cloud animation into this jsfiddle - jsfiddle.net/xpb90keq –

---

latest version 14th December - please use this as a base.
https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-tdd-57ov7?file=/src/MagicCloud.js

animating left to right
https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-lamarr-qhw8k

---

latest version 15th December -
https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-wood-wjnd5  -- latest I got - but not sure why the bubbles linger at the top

Comment: I've tried this - https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-satoshi-knusw -- but its not really fizzing the way I envision -- want it to fade into existence, fade out as it reaches the top -- and really appear around the cloud - towards the half way mark - and not behind it so. Not sure how to control these better

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-allen-icj0j -- need to add more mixins

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.cssscript.com/bubble-confetti-effect-button/
It uses an animated backgroud, maybe you can copy some ideas.

Comment: animation isn't really the same

Comment: -- latest approach -- but the bubbles don't start/end where I need them - https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-dream-08ueh

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nsrte6g5/  almost working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n139wod0/3/  --- latest version with scale of bubble - animation bottom to up - and fade in, fade out --

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-wood-wjnd5  -- latest I got - but not sure why the bubbles linger at the top

Comment: @TheOldCounty Will my version work for u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Its a pure CSS version of cloud fizzy bubble effect

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -140px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.cloud,
.cloud_small,
.fizz {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.cloud {
  z-index: 11;
}

.cloud_small {
  z-index: 12;
}

.cloud i {
  font-size: 135px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.cloud_small i {
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 110px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg)scale(1.05, 1.05);
}

.fizz {
  margin-top: -70px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.fizz .small {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FF5D00;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: fizz_out 2s linear infinite;
}

.small:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #FF8038;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  animation: fizz_out 2s 1.5s linear infinite;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.fizz .small_border {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #C900FF;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  animation: fizz_out 2s 0.5s linear infinite;
}

.small_border:nth-child(3) {
  border-color: #FF0061;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: -70px;
  animation: fizz_out 2s 1s linear infinite;
}

.fizz .star {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #FFB600;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 61% 35%, 100% 49%, 64% 61%, 59% 73%, 50% 100%, 44% 74%, 35% 61%, 0 50%, 39% 35%);
  animation: fizz_out_star 3s 1s linear infinite;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.fizz .star:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #FFF300;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  animation: fizz_out_star 3s 2s linear infinite;
}

.fizz .star:nth-child(6) {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  animation: fizz_out_star 3s 2.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes fizz_out {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  35% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-120px);
  }
}

@keyframes fizz_out_star {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0px)rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-120px)rotateZ(720deg);
  }
}

.back {
  filter: blur(1px);
  transform: scale(0.6)rotateY(180deg)translateX(-30px);
}

.back .small {
  transform: translateX(-10px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="cloud">
  <div class="exit"></div>
  <i class="fa fa-cloud"></i>
</div>
<div class="cloud_small">
  <i class="fa fa-cloud"></i>
</div>

<div class="fizz">
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small_border"></div>
  <div class="small_border"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
</div>
<div class="fizz back">
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small_border"></div>
  <div class="small_border"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had some fadein and out going on

Comment: @TheOldCounty i edited the code as per your requirement

Comment: it should still fade in - before its seen - and fade out - before it leaves -

Comment: its still cut as it leaves?

Comment: @TheOldCounty If you need fadeIn effect a bit later i rectified that problem

Comment: fade in and fade out - before it hits the top

Comment: @TheOldCounty now see the output

Comment: still cuts at the top?

Comment: needs to fade out before it hits the top

Comment: some are still getting cut as they pass the top?

Comment: @TheOldCounty which one can u be more specific

Comment: gold star -- purple circle with white inside

Comment: @TheOldCounty edit done now will this work for u

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226168/discussion-between-the-old-county-and-ac-mmi).

Comment: but I did get this working in the scss I had used -- if you check out the other thread - "This was the solution I used" - cause it takes a mix of shapes - you don't need to write your css so specific

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve something like that with absolute animated element encapsulate in a wrapper that contains the icon. Then you position these elements with pourcentage and animate them with a little delay to looks more natural. My tiny example looks like this:

```css
.magic-cloud {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.bubble {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: bubbling .5s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.bubble:nth-of-type(even) {
  animation-delay: .2s;
}

.bubble.red:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: 40%;
}

.bubble.red:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}

.bubble.red:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 30%;
  right: 20%;
}

.bubble.blue:nth-of-type(4) {
  top: 20%;
  right: 30%;
}

.bubble.blue:nth-of-type(5) {
  top: 10%;
  left: 30%;
}

.bubble.pink:nth-of-type(6) {
  top: 15%;
  left: 40%;
}

.bubble.pink:nth-of-type(7) {
  top: 45%;
  right: 10%;
}

.bubble.pink:nth-of-type(8) {
  top: 35%;
  left: 20%;
}

.red {
  border-color: red;
}

.blue {
  border-color: blue;
}

.pink {
  border-color: pink;
}

@keyframes bubbling {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-400%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="magic-cloud">
  <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root large" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
    <path d="M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4 9.11 4 6.6 5.64 5.35 8.04 2.34 8.36 0 10.91 0 14c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6h13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5 0-2.64-2.05-4.78-4.65-4.96zM19 18H6c-2.21 0-4-1.79-4-4s1.79-4 4-4h.71C7.37 7.69 9.48 6 12 6c3.04 0 5.5 2.46 5.5 5.5v.5H19c1.66 0 3 1.34 3 3s-1.34 3-3 3z"></path>
  </svg>
  <div class="bubble red"></div>
  <div class="bubble red"></div>
  <div class="bubble red"></div>
  <div class="bubble blue"></div>
  <div class="bubble blue"></div>
  <div class="bubble pink"></div>
  <div class="bubble pink"></div>
  <div class="bubble pink"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-dream-08ueh?file=/src/MagicCloud.js  -- I've got something going with this in css3 - where they also drift left/right - but I can't seem to fix the mixin or see why my bubbles aren't really noticeable inside that area of influence?

Comment: I've put your cloud animation into this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xpb90keq/

Comment: here is my version - but the shapes although I can see them floating aren't really showing up -- http://jsfiddle.net/xpb90keq/3/

Comment: how do you modify yours to use the @content method? - https://brandonbrule.github.io/scss-animation-keyframe-mixin/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n139wod0/4/  - I had to use a hoist -- this is starting to take shape

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-wood-wjnd5  -- latest I got - but not sure why the bubbles linger at the top

Answer (score 0):

This is the latest version I have - but I want to tidy up the sass

```css
    
.magic-cloud {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;

  .smaller {
    .MuiSvgIcon-root {
      font-size: 11px;
    }
  }

  .small {
    .MuiSvgIcon-root {
      font-size: 15px;
    }
  }

  .gold {
    color: #f8ac00;
  }

  .pink {
    color: #dfb2c1;
  }

  .purple {
    color: #8d3e82;
  }

  .blue {
    color: #cbdff1;
  }

  .lavendar {
    color: #af699e;
  }


  .lucky-cloud-container {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);


    .cloud {
      font-size: 146px;
    }

    .lucky-charms-container {
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      width: 200px;
      height: 70px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .lucky-charms {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      background: red;
    }

  }



}

@mixin transform($property) {
  -webkit-transform: $property;
  -ms-transform: $property;
  transform: $property;
}


@mixin animation($group1, $group2) {
  -webkit-animation: $group1, $group2;
  -moz-animation: $group1, $group2;
  -o-animation: $group1, $group2;
}


@mixin opacity($property) {
  -webkit-opacity: $property;
  -ms-opacity: $property;
  opacity: $property;
}



@mixin keyframe ($animation_name) {
  @-webkit-keyframes $animation_name {
    @content;
  }

  @-moz-keyframes $animation_name {
    @content;
  }

  @-o-keyframes $animation_name {
    @content;
  }

  @keyframes $animation_name {
    @content;
  }
}




@mixin bubbleProps($scale, $opacity, $timing1, $timing2, $left) {
  //@include transform(scale($scale));
  @include animation(moveclouds $timing1 linear infinite, sideWays $timing2 ease-in-out infinite);
  @include opacity($opacity);
  left: $left;

  /*
  @include keyframe(animation-slide-in-up) {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0,100%);
    }
  
    100% {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }
  }*/

}


.bubble {
  position: absolute;
}

.fizz-1 {
  @include bubbleProps(0.6, 0.2, 10s, 4s, 5%);
}

.fizz-2 {
  @include bubbleProps(0.8, 0.4, 15s, 2s, 20%);
}

.fizz-3 {
  @include bubbleProps(0.9, 0.6, 25s, 6s, 50%);
}





@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
  0% {
    top: 500px;
  }

  100% {
    top: -500px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
  0% {
    top: 500px;
  }

  100% {
    top: -500px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
  0% {
    top: 500px;
  }

  100% {
    top: -500px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes sideWays {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="magic-cloud">
  <div class="lucky-cloud-container"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root cloud" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
  <path d="M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4 9.11 4 6.6 5.64 5.35 8.04 2.34 8.36 0 10.91 0 14c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6h13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5 0-2.64-2.05-4.78-4.65-4.96zM19 18H6c-2.21 0-4-1.79-4-4s1.79-4 4-4h.71C7.37 7.69 9.48 6 12 6c3.04 0 5.5 2.46 5.5 5.5v.5H19c1.66 0 3 1.34 3 3s-1.34 3-3 3z"></path>
</svg>
<div>Drag and drop to upload</div>
<div class="lucky-charms">
  <div class="lucky-charms-container">
    <div class="bubble small gold fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="8"></circle>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small pink fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small gold fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller gold fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller gold fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="8"></circle>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller purple fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small lavendar fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small lavendar fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small lavendar fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller lavendar fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small purple fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small gold fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small pink fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="8"></circle>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller purple fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller gold fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small pink fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small blue fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small blue fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="8"></circle>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller purple fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller pink fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small lavendar fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small blue fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="8"></circle>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small lavendar fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller gold fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller purple fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small purple fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="8"></circle>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small gold fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small lavendar fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small purple fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small gold fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="8"></circle>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small pink fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="8"></circle>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small purple fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="8"></circle>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller pink fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller pink fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small pink fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small gold fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small blue fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small pink fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller blue fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small blue fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="8"></circle>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller pink fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small gold fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small gold fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller pink fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller lavendar fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="8"></circle>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small blue fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble small blue fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller pink fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="8"></circle>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller blue fizz-1"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <div class="bubble smaller lavendar fizz-2"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="8"></circle>
      </svg></div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I used.

```
@import '../../../colors.scss';

.magic-cloud {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;

  .smaller {
    .MuiSvgIcon-root {
      font-size: 11px;
    }
  }

  .small {
    .MuiSvgIcon-root {
      font-size: 19px;
    }
  }

  .gold {
    color: #f8ac00;
  }

  .pink {
    color: #dfb2c1;
  }

  .purple {
    color: #8d3e82;
  }

  .blue {
    color: #cbdff1;
  }

  .lavendar {
    color: #af699e;
  }

  .lucky-cloud-container {
    position: relative;

    svg.cloud {
        font-size: 146px;
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
    }

    .lucky-charms-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 146px;
        height: 85px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .lucky-charms {
        position: absolute;
        top: -15px;
    }

  }

}

@mixin keyframe ($animation_name) {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$animation_name} {
        @content;
    }

    @-moz-keyframes #{$animation_name} {
        @content;
    }

    @-o-keyframes #{$animation_name} {
        @content;
    }

    @keyframes #{$animation_name} {
        @content;
    }
}


@mixin animation ($delay, $duration, $animation, $direction: forward, $fillmode: fowards, $iterations: infinite) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: $delay;
    -webkit-animation-duration: $duration;
    -webkit-animation-name: $animation;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: $fillmode;
    -webkit-animation-direction: $direction;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: $iterations;

    -moz-animation-delay: $delay;
    -moz-animation-duration: $duration;
    -moz-animation-name: $animation;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: $fillmode;
    -moz-animation-direction: $direction;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: $iterations;

    animation-delay: $delay;
    animation-duration: $duration;
    animation-name: $animation;
    animation-fill-mode: $fillmode;
    animation-direction: $direction;
    animation-iteration-count: $iterations;
}


@mixin transform($property) {
    -webkit-transform: $property;
    -ms-transform: $property;
    transform: $property;
}


@mixin opacity($property) {
    -webkit-opacity: $property;
    -ms-opacity: $property;
    opacity: $property;
}


@mixin bubbleProps($scale, $opacity, $timing1, $left) {
    @include transform(scale($scale));
    @include animation(0, $timing1, animation-slide-in-up, linear);
    @include opacity($opacity);
    left: $left;
}


.bubble {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    .bubble-wrap{
        position:relative;
        .MuiSvgIcon-root{
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
        }
    }

}


.fizz-0 {
  @include bubbleProps(0.4, 0.8, 1.4s, 80%);
}

.fizz-1 {
  @include bubbleProps(0.6, 0.2, 2s, 5%);
}

.fizz-2 {
  @include bubbleProps(0.3, 0.4, 4s, 20%);
}

.fizz-3 {
  @include bubbleProps(0.1, 0.9, 5s, 50%);
}

.fizz-4 {
  @include bubbleProps(0.2, 0.6, 1.6s, 70%);
}

.fizz-5 {
  @include bubbleProps(0.1, 0.9, 2s, 20%);
}

.fizz-6 {
  @include bubbleProps(0.2, 0.6, 1.2s, 34%);
}


@include keyframe(animation-slide-in-up) {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(-5%, 200%);
    }
    10% { 
        opacity: 1; 
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(5%, 0%);
    }
}
```